# React: Stumped with how to select table rows with a checkbox and send the values to the server side with node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello I am working on a process with React that will allow users to select a row or rows from a table by selecting check-boxes.

I need assistance with how once a row is checked, how can I store this information but at the same time if the row is unchecked I would also want to update the state.

Than when the user selects the submit button it will send the array object to the server side.

I have an empty array in my state and in the method that handles selecting a checkbox I am attempting to push the data to the array and than send the array with a form.

It appears as if the array is not being updated or I am missing something?

```
 class TestStatus extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
       super(props)

      this.state = {
         selected: []
      }

 handleCheckChildeElement = (event) => {
    var data = this.global.data;

    data.forEach(data => {
        if(data.testid === event.target.value) {
            data.isChecked = event.target.checked

            if(event.target.checked === true) {
                this.setState({ selected: [ ...this.state.selected, data] 
               });
            }

            console.log(this.state.selected);
        }
    });
    this.setGlobal({ data });
  }

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/advanced_cleanup', 
       this.state.selected)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("Sending tests");
        }).catch(event => console.log(event));
}

render() {
   return(

   <div>

    <table>
       <AdvancedRows checked={this.handleCheckChildeElement} 
        handleCheckChildeElement={this.handleCheckChildeElement}/>
    </table>

    <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

     <button 
           className="ui basic blue button" type="submit"
           style={{ marginBottom: '5em' }}>
           Submit
     </button>

   </form>

   </div>
  );
 }

}
```

I expect to be able to select a checkbox or multiple and update the state array based on what is checked and than send that data to the server side.

Comment: setState is async, you may not see it in your console.log after setting the state right away.

Comment: Ahh I see you are correct. I am able to console.log the req.body and see the object. Now I just need to figure out a good flow for managing the selected check boxes and when they un-select a checkbox to update the selected array. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Since you're looping through the checkboxes (I believe), you could set the state of `selected` to an empty array before `data.forEach`. This way, the state will be cleaned everytime you check/uncheck a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional research online I found the correct way with react to update the state array and than update it upon unchecking a check box.

If the targeted row is checked it will pass that rows object into the state array otherwise if the check box of the row is unchecked it will iterate over the state array and filter out the item that was unchecked.

This is the guide I used to assist me. https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/reactjs-update-array-state.html

```
  if(event.target.checked === true) {
    this.setState({ selected: [...this.state.selected, data ] });

  } else {
    let remove = this.state.selected.map(function(item) {
    return item.testid}).indexOf(event.target.value);

    this.setState({ selected: this.state.selected.filter((_, i) => i !== remove) }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above.

```
 handleCheckChildeElement = (event) => {
    var data = this.global.data;
    // create an empty array so that each click will clean/update your state
    var checkedData = [];

    data.forEach(data => {
        if(data.testid === event.target.value) {
            data.isChecked = event.target.checked

            if(event.target.checked === true) {
                // instead of setting your state here, push to your array
                checkedData.push(data);
            }

            console.log(checkedData);
        }
    });
    // setState with updated checked values
    this.setState({selected: checkedData});
    this.setGlobal({ data });
  }
```

Comment: That got me thinking in the right direction but ultimately I was able to follow a guide and do the following,
    if(event.target.checked === true) {
                    this.setState({ selected: [...this.state.selected, data ] });

                } else {
                    let remove = this.state.selected.map(function(item) { return 
    item.testid; }).indexOf(event.target.value);
                    this.setState({
                        selected: this.state.selected.filter((_, i) => i !== remove)
                      });
                }

Comment: ahh, that makes sense too. Glad you were able to solve it. You may want to post that as the answer and accept it.